# How to push json data into array in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

How do i get data in $scope.moduleSelected into label in the treedata_avm array instead of the hardcoded values present in the array?

```
app.controller('treeController',['$http','$scope','dataService',function( $http,$scope,dataService){

    $http.get('WS/tree').success(function(data,status){
        $scope.modules=data;
        $scope.moduleSelected = $scope.modules[0].MODULE_NAME;
        $scope.moduleSelectedId = $scope.modules[0].ID;
        $scope.moduleSelectedParentId = $scope.modules[0].PARENT_ID;

     console.log($scope.modules);
     console.log($scope.moduleSelected);
     console.log($scope.moduleSelectedId);
     console.log($scope.moduleSelectedParentId);


    }).error(function(data){
        $scope.modules=data || "Request failed";
        console.log("Request failed "+ $scope.modules);
    });

    }]);
```

treedata_avm:

```
treedata_avm = [
  {
    label: 'Animal',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Dog',

      }, {
        label: 'Cat',

      }, {
        label: 'Hippopotamus',

      }, {
        label: 'Chicken',
        children: ['White Leghorn', 'Rhode Island Red', 'Jersey Giant']
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: How do i get data in  $scope.moduleSelected into label in the treedata_avm array instead of the hardcoded values present in the array?

Answer (score 0):

`$http` with its `success` promise resolve function returns data in the current format: `response.data`

Meaning in your case you should first set

```
$http.get('WS/tree').success(function(response){
    $scope.modules = response.data;
    $scope.treedata_avm = response.data
}).error(function (){...})
```

If you are going to use your `treedata_avm` on a view, then it should be on the $scope as in `$scope.treedata_avm` if not then just use it as a variable inside the controller

Also my advice would be to put all of this `$http` logic into a provider (factory, service, provider) and then invoke it from there.
The advice is to make controllers as thin as possible and put the logic inside the providers (factories, services, providers), thus making it reausable

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to event 'onchange' on the field, that's bound to $scope.moduleSelected and change your json when input field is changed. But I can't see, why would you need something like this?